# OpenOffice Headless

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openoffice.org, headless

Around a year ago I installed OpenOffice on Ubuntu Server and didn't have any problems. I believe it was:

sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-headless openoffice.org-writer

Now it just tells me that it is unable to locate the package. I've tried all conceivable variations of the same. All of the examples I find don't work any longer. Is it my ubuntu installation or are others having the problem? Does this have something to do with everyone moving to LibreOffice? Is there an equivalent for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question hence off topic here. You would get better answer on askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I need to install OpenOffice headless on a server, I just install the Writer without the recommended packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends openoffice.org-writer
```

It pulls in only the strict dependencies for it to run, which is ok on a server environment.